# What happens if apex:facet name="start" or apex:facet name="stop"?

Tags: visualforce-component

I am very much confused of using apex:facet component in my visualforce development when I came across a code snippet as follows. The value for the name attribute is given as "start" and "stop". Does "start" and "stop" meant anything in this context? What is the actual use of apex:facet here? Please suggest.

```
      <apex:actionStatus id="TableUpdateStatus"> 
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!AlphaFilter}" id="hiddenField" />
        <!-- loading message -->
        <apex:facet name="start">
           <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="message infoM4">
              <apex:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="messageTable" columnClasses="messageCell" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                 <apex:panelGroup >
                    <img class="loading-icon" src="/s.gif" />
                 </apex:panelGroup>
                 <apex:panelGroup >
                    <div class="messageText">Please wait...</div>
                 </apex:panelGroup>
              </apex:panelGrid>
           </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:facet>

        <!-- Account table -->
        <apex:facet name="stop">
           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CurrentAccountList}" var="a">
              <apex:column >
                 <apex:commandLink styleClass="alpha-link" action="{!DoSomethingOne}">
                    <apex:param value="{!a.aAccount.Id}" assignTo="{!SelectedOneAccount}" />Select</apex:commandLink>
              </apex:column>
```

Comment: Experts, Thanks for the splendid answers here. Now i really confused to choose the best among the best.

Answer (score 3):

From the [apex:facet](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_facet.htm) documentation:

> An `<apex:facet>` component can only exist in the body of a parent
>   component if the parent supports facets. The name of the facet
>   component must match one of the pre-defined facet names on the parent
>   component. This name determines where the content of the facet
>   component is rendered. The order in which a facet component is defined
>   within the body of a parent component doesn't affect the appearance of
>   the parent component.

In your code example the parent component is [apex:actionStatus](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionStatus.htm), which has two pre-defined facet names:

> - **start** - The components that display when an AJAX request begins. Use this facet as an alternative to the startText attribute.
>     Note that the order in which a start facet appears in the body of an
>     actionStatus component does not matter, because any facet with the
>     attribute name="start" controls the appearance of the actionStatus
>     component when the request begins.
> - **stop** - The components that display when an AJAX request completes. Use this facet as an alternative to the stopText attribute.
>     Note that the order in which a stop facet appears in the body of an
>     actionStatus component does not matter, because any facet with the
>     attribute name="stop" controls the appearance of the actionStatus
>     component when the request completes.

Everything wrapped by `<apex:facet name="start">` will get displayed when the AJAX request begins and everything wrapped by `<apex:facet name="stop">` will get displayed when the AJAX request completes

Comment: It looks like your code snippet is taken from http://www.davehelgerson.com/?p=549

Comment: Exactly @BarCotter. I tried to use the idea in it, but confused by the behavior of apex:facet. Because some of the component are not all displaying when i used in my code and do not know the reason of why?

Answer (score 2):

From : https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_facet.htm

> Another component that can use a facet is `<apex:actionStatus>`. The `<apex:actionStatus>` component can be extended to display an indicator whenever a page is being refreshed. For example, you can define a progress wheel with the following markup:
>
> ```
> <apex:page controller="exampleCon">
>     <apex:form >
>         <apex:outputText value="Watch this counter: {!count}" id="counter"/>
>         <apex:actionStatus id="counterStatus">
>             <apex:facet name="start">
>                  <img src="{!$Resource.spin}"/> <!-- A previously defined image -->
>             </apex:facet>
>         </apex:actionStatus>    
>         <apex:actionPoller action="{!incrementCounter}" rerender="counter"
>             status="counterStatus" interval="7"/>
>     </apex:form>
> </apex:page>
> ```

You can define HTML blocks to use at the start and stop of an actionstatus. Start being what is shown while the AJAX request is running and stop after its complete.

Answer (score 1):

Facets are used to inject more functionality into things that normally will only accept a text value, or URL.

One way that facets are frequently used is to make table and column headers much more interesting. By using facet, you can take what would normally be a simple label, and you could turn it into a whole little HTML snippet that could include images, links, and event handlers for manipulating the UI.

The "thing" the facet will override is identified by the `name` attribute. In this instance, one is `start` and the other is `stop`. These will point to features or attributes of the facet tags parent. To trim things down, you have this:

```
<apex:actionStatus ...>
    <apex:facet name="start">  <----override the start action of actionStatus
        this is the stuff that will appear when the start of some partial page refresh occurs
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:facet name="stop">  <----override the stop action of actionStatus
        this is the stuff that will appear when the end of some partial page refresh occurs
    </apex:facet>
</apex:actionStatus>
```

So to know what these facets will do, you could check the docs to find out how `start` and `stop` attributes behave on `apex:actionStatus`.

Basically, `apex:actionStatus` is a bit of UI that will appear and disappear when native VF AJAX calls occur. Normally you would use `startText` to show some text like "loading..." when the AJAX call starts. `stopText` would appear when it was done.

In this case specifically, it look as if they are using the `start` facet to make a message appear, but with a lot of additional formatting, some extra CSS, and an image/icon.

Stop seems to be rendering some links when finished.

The missing piece from your code extract is what kicks this off. You would need to look for a button, link, or some other `action` that refers to the id of this facet: TableUpdateStatus.

Answer (score 1):

I use `start` and `stop` facets in between when a `commandAction`/`commandLink` is called and when it completes and re-renders the part of the page.

For example, I have a multi-step wizard on one VF Page, and I only display one section at a time.

```
<apex:page controller="MultiStepWizard" >
     <apex:actionStatus id="loading" onstart="doOnSubmit();" onstop="doOnRerender();">
         <apex:facet name="start">
             <div class="loadingBackground">
                 <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.theSpinner)}" id="spinner" class="spin"/>
             </div>
         </apex:facet> 
         <apex:facet name="stop"></apex:facet>   
    </apex:actionStatus>
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!currentTab = 'Section 1'}">
            ...
            <apex:commandButton value="{!sectionMap[currentTab].nextSection}" action={!"goToSection}" 
                                status="loading" reRender="theForm">
                <apex:param assignTo="{!nextTab}" value="{!sectionMap[currentTab].nextSection}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!currentTab = 'Section 2}">
            ... etc.
```

I want to provide seamless transitions from section to section, so I re-render the form when switching tabs.  Since `commandAction`s take a few seconds roundtrip, I want the user to feel something is processing when switching sections (while I'm saving the current tab's `SectionData` and initializing the next tab's `SectionData`), so I use an `actionStatus` to display a loading spinnor over the full screen with the `start facet` and then remove the spinnor with the `stop facet`.